# Convert LINQ query to Sqlquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I need help to convert this query from LINQ syntax into SQLServer query syntax:

```
var t1 = (from p in db.Varors join
          op in db.OrderVarors on p.id equals op.IdVara
          where op.IdOrder == OrderId
          select p).ToList();
```

Comment: Replace ToList by ToString...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:-

```
SELECT v.* from Varors v
JOIN ordervarors ov on v.id = ov.id
where ov.idOrder == @OrderId
```

Comment: correction: `v.id` needs to be equal to `ov.IdVara`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to choose individual columns instead of star but this should work.

```
select * 
from dbo.Varors as P
join dbo.OrderVarors as OP 
    on p.id equals op.IdVara
where op.IdOrder = OrderId
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple **join** - try this :

```
select Varors.* 
from Varors
join OrderVarors on Varors.id = OrderVarors.IdVara
where OrderVarors.IdOrder = @OrderId
```